# How to Troubleshoot ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've just installed ASP.NET MVC on my Vista x64 box, and created a default ASP.NET MVC project with no modifications. When I attempt to browse the application, I simply get the usual useless "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" message.

I've tried setting a breakpoint in Global.asax, but it's not being hit at all. Cassini seems to be running as it's supposed to.

I have another Vista x64 machine where ASP.NET MVC works fine. The only differences I can think of between those two machines is that on the box where it doesn't work, I have also installed the F# CTP and Visual Studio 2010 beta 1.

Can anyone suggest how I can troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Are you running the app within VS.NET?

Comment: Is a firewall rule or antivirus program blocking the requests?

Comment: I'm running from within VS.NET, and I've tried to disable the Windows Firewall to no avail. Further investigation shows that I have the same problem with "normal" ASP.NET web applications, so apparently, the issue is more general. If I set a site up to run in IIS, it works, so the issue seems to be with Cassini.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue is now resolved. It turned out to be a problem with IPv6 - read more [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqldev/archive/2009/03/12/asp-net-development-server-is-not-working-with-ipv6.aspx).

The solution involving the *hosts* file worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set this up as an application in IIS?  If so, if you are using IIS6 then you will need to do extra work in the global.asax file namely with the routes.

Google MVC and IIS6 and you should find the solution.

Comment: Vista (and Windows Server 2008) only support IIS7, so this can't be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the web application with the Visual Studio debugger attached and set a breakpoint in your Global.asax.cs on this method (add this if it's not already present):

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

All requests within your application should go through this method and break. By stepping through the code, you may also find the problem...

You could also try requesting a static file, to ensure you have set up everything correctly.