# MVC web fails after move

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC website that was working fine on one dev machine.  I moved it to a new dev machine and navigation to anything but the default index fails with a resource not found error.  I've set breakpoints in all the controllers and nothing is being hit.  Both machines are .net 3.5 sp1, MVC v1.0.  The original dev machine was XP, the new one is VISTA.  I've successfully worked other MVC projects on the new machine before.

Any ideas of what to check?

Comment: Well this is.. embarassing.  It seems that between the last time and this time I re-imaged the VISTA machine, and it no longer had IIS installed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Url mapping works different on IIS 6.0 and IIS 7.0 (vista) so that could be the reason.
Check this article to find more info
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: Thanks for making me go look at IIS!  Here's to not assuming.  I thought I'd installed IIS on this machine, but forgot that I had re-imaged since then.  That's what I get for assuming...

Comment: Turns out that didn't fix it, still digging

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of IPv6 on Windows Vista. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060724/how-to-troubleshoot-asp-net-mvc/1064976#1064976) for more details.